# Migrate WildFly 26.x/27.x Mojarra to Jakarta 10 MyFaces 4.0.0.RC2

Tags: jsf, jakarta-ee, wildfly, myfaces

Using: WildFly 26.1.2.Final & Preview-27.0.0.Beta1 with Jakarta 10.0.

As an issue I have with PrimeFaces 'TabView' (7.x - 12.x) using Mojarra (now 4.0.0.SP01) with WildFly 26.1.2.Final/Preview-27.0.0.Beta1. It has been suggested I migrate to MyFaces.

I've followed the guides at:

https://access.redhat.com/documentation/en-us/red_hat_jboss_enterprise_application_platform/7.2/html/configuration_guide/javaserver_faces_jsf_configuration#doc-wrapper

&

https://docs.wildfly.org/26/Admin_Guide.html#Jakarta_Server_Faces

Set & run:

```
./jboss-cli.sh -c "/subsystem=jsf/:write-attribute(name=default-jsf-impl-slot,value=myfaces-4.0.0-RC2)"
{
    "outcome" => "success",
    "response-headers" => {
        "operation-requires-reload" => true,
        "process-state" => "reload-required"
    }
}

{"outcome" => "success"}
```

Using MyFaces 4.0.0-RC2 I deploy my EAR & I get:

```
14:34:28,769 WARN  [org.jboss.as.jsf] (MSC service thread 1-2) WFLYJSF0005: Unknown Jakarta Server Faces version 'myfaces-4.0.0-RC2'.  Default version 'myfaces-4.0.0-RC2' will be used instead.
14:34:28,770 ERROR [org.jboss.msc.service.fail] (MSC service thread 1-2) MSC000001: Failed to start service jboss.deployment.unit."NOTiFYmoto.ear".DEPENDENCIES: org.jboss.msc.service.StartException in service jboss.deployment.unit."NOTiFYmoto.ear".DEPENDENCIES: WFLYSRV0153: Failed to process phase DEPENDENCIES of deployment "NOTiFYmoto.ear"
    at org.jboss.as.server@19.0.0.Beta18//org.jboss.as.server.deployment.DeploymentUnitPhaseService.start(DeploymentUnitPhaseService.java:189)
    at org.jboss.msc@1.4.13.Final//org.jboss.msc.service.ServiceControllerImpl$StartTask.startService(ServiceControllerImpl.java:1739)
    at org.jboss.msc@1.4.13.Final//org.jboss.msc.service.ServiceControllerImpl$StartTask.execute(ServiceControllerImpl.java:1701)
    at org.jboss.msc@1.4.13.Final//org.jboss.msc.service.ServiceControllerImpl$ControllerTask.run(ServiceControllerImpl.java:1559)
    at org.jboss.threads@2.4.0.Final//org.jboss.threads.ContextClassLoaderSavingRunnable.run(ContextClassLoaderSavingRunnable.java:35)
    at org.jboss.threads@2.4.0.Final//org.jboss.threads.EnhancedQueueExecutor.safeRun(EnhancedQueueExecutor.java:1990)
    at org.jboss.threads@2.4.0.Final//org.jboss.threads.EnhancedQueueExecutor$ThreadBody.doRunTask(EnhancedQueueExecutor.java:1486)
    at org.jboss.threads@2.4.0.Final//org.jboss.threads.EnhancedQueueExecutor$ThreadBody.run(EnhancedQueueExecutor.java:1377)
    at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:833)
Caused by: org.jboss.as.server.deployment.DeploymentUnitProcessingException: WFLYJSF0014: Default Jakarta Server Faces implementation slot 'myfaces-4.0.0-RC2' is invalid
    at org.jboss.as.jsf@27.0.0.Beta1//org.jboss.as.jsf.deployment.JSFDependencyProcessor.deploy(JSFDependencyProcessor.java:94)
    at org.jboss.as.server@19.0.0.Beta18//org.jboss.as.server.deployment.DeploymentUnitPhaseService.start(DeploymentUnitPhaseService.java:182)
    ... 8 more

14:34:28,772 ERROR [org.jboss.as.controller.management-operation] (External Management Request Threads -- 1) WFLYCTL0013: Operation ("add") failed - address: ([("deployment" => "NOTiFYmoto.ear")]) - failure description: {"WFLYCTL0080: Failed services" => {"jboss.deployment.unit.\"NOTiFYmoto.ear\".DEPENDENCIES" => "WFLYSRV0153: Failed to process phase DEPENDENCIES of deployment \"NOTiFYmoto.ear\"
    Caused by: org.jboss.as.server.deployment.DeploymentUnitProcessingException: WFLYJSF0014: Default Jakarta Server Faces implementation slot 'myfaces-4.0.0-RC2' is invalid"}}
14:34:28,773 ERROR [org.jboss.as.controller.management-operation] (External Management Request Threads -- 1) WFLYCTL0013: Operation ("add") failed - address: ([("deployment" => "NOTiFYmoto.ear")]) - failure description: {"WFLYCTL0080: Failed services" => {"jboss.deployment.unit.\"NOTiFYmoto.ear\".DEPENDENCIES" => "WFLYSRV0153: Failed to process phase DEPENDENCIES of deployment \"NOTiFYmoto.ear\"
    Caused by: org.jboss.as.server.deployment.DeploymentUnitProcessingException: WFLYJSF0014: Default Jakarta Server Faces implementation slot 'myfaces-4.0.0-RC2' is invalid"}}
14:34:28,775 ERROR [org.jboss.as.server] (External Management Request Threads -- 1) WFLYSRV0021: Deploy of deployment "NOTiFYmoto.ear" was rolled back with the following failure message: 
{"WFLYCTL0080: Failed services" => {"jboss.deployment.unit.\"NOTiFYmoto.ear\".DEPENDENCIES" => "WFLYSRV0153: Failed to process phase DEPENDENCIES of deployment \"NOTiFYmoto.ear\"
    Caused by: org.jboss.as.server.deployment.DeploymentUnitProcessingException: WFLYJSF0014: Default Jakarta Server Faces implementation slot 'myfaces-4.0.0-RC2' is invalid"}}
```

(2) Also both:

```
/usr/local/Cellar/wildfly-as/wildfly-preview-27.0.0.Beta1.MyFaces/modules/system/layers/base/org/wildfly/extension/clustering/web
```

References 'mojarra':

```
<module name="org.wildfly.clustering.faces.mojarra"/>
```

and:

```
/usr/local/Cellar/wildfly-as/wildfly-preview-27.0.0.Beta1.MyFaces/modules/system/layers/base/org/wildfly/extension/clustering
```

also references 'mojarra':

```
<module name="org.wildfly.clustering.faces.mojarra" xmlns="urn:jboss:module:1.9">

    <properties>
        <property name="jboss.api" value="private"/>
    </properties>

    <resources>
        <resource-root path="wildfly-clustering-faces-mojarra-27.0.0.Beta1.jar"/>
```

This error when I follow the "Jakarta Server Faces Configuration".

Any pointers or ideas etc? TIA.

Comment: Are you aware that MyFaces 2.3.x is not Jakarta EE 10 compatible? You need MyFaces 4.0.x.

Comment: Thanks. Upgraded to "MyFaces-4.0.0-RC2" for Jakarta. Still errors.